# Partial fraction decompostion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Solve the partial fraction.

Starting out with...

$${x^2+1\over x^3-1}={x^2+1\over (x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$$

Then the partial fraction formula part of $\displaystyle {A\over x-1}+{Bx+C\over x^2+x+1}$.

Solving with the "shortcut" method of substitution, here is what came up.

Multiplying the partial fraction part by the problem,

$${x^2+1\over x^3-1}={x^2+1\over (x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=
{A\over x-1}+{Bx+C\over x^2+x+1}
$$

is

$$x^2+1=A(x^2+x+1)+B(Bx+C)(x-1)$$

Then letting

$x=1$ then $2=3A$, $~~A=\frac23$

$x=0$ then $1=A-C$, then $C=-\frac{1}3$

$x=-1$ then 
$$\eqalign{2&=A(-2(-B)+C)=A+2B-2C=\frac23+2B-2\left(-\frac13\right)=\frac43+2B\cr
2-\frac43&=2B\cr}
$$
$B=  \frac13$

Then factoring, the answer is $\displaystyle{1\over3}\left({2\over x-1}+{x-1\over x^2+x+1}\right)$.

Is there any possible quicker way, or is this the fastest?

Answer (score 13):

Just to be clear, I think you meant that the partial fraction problem is reduced to finding the coefficients for

$x^2+1=A(x^2+x+1)+(Bx+C)(x-1)$

Solving with the method of substitution is indeed probably the quickest way. But note that the coefficient method reveals valuable information.

For example, since the $x^2$ on the LHS has coefficient 1, we expect that $A+B=1  \quad (Ax^2+Bx^2=x^2$)

An obvious substitution like you did would be at $x=1$. Then, $3A=2\Rightarrow A=2/3; B=1/3$

Another apparent coefficient is the last one. $1=A-C \Rightarrow C=-1/3$

Either methods work fine but the coefficient method is very powerful. In terms of efficiency, they will be around the same, with a slight advantage towards the coefficient method.